# How to make the URLs unclickable?

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++, how can I remove hyperlinks from text that consists of copied and pasted URLs?

**Note:** I do NOT want to change the overall behaviour of Notepad++. I just want to remove the hyperlinks from SOME of the text I have. I want to do this on the fly, as required and not as the general default setting.

The screenshot shows a scenario. I want to remove the link from row 9, so I can just click into the text and the link is not opened.

In Word or other text apps, I can just right-click and remove the hyperlink, while the text remains the same. How do I do that in Notepad++?

[image]

Comment: Remove the `http://` or `https://` preceding the link.

Comment: @Toto I added more details.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I want to keep all text, just remove the link behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I don't think this is possible, at least if you don't want to change the overall behaviour of Notepad++

Comment: Just as a hint, as "remove" sounds like there is a link embedded in the text document: notepad++ highlights all words starting with "http(s)://" as clickable links, when the setting is set, but those are not stored in any way as links in the resulting text file (like Word does in doc(x)). This also means there is no native way to save/remember which such word in which text file to show as link and which not, unless notepad++ creates an extensive per-file database, or such.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot chose which links are and are not clickable without removing the http(s):// prefix.

You can make all URLs not clickable:

Open Notepad++ and go to Settings>Preferences. In the Preferences window, click the MISC. tab and under the 'Clickable Link Settings' section uncheck the 'Enable' checkbox.

This option is moved to Settings > Preferences... > Cloud & Link option

Comment: (Re)read the question `I do NOT want to change the overall behaviour of Notepad++. `

Comment: @Toto (Re)read the answer `You cannot chose which links are and are not clickable...`

Comment: No needs to reread, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Toto It clearly does. "That cannot be done" is a valid answer.

Comment: No, it should be a comment as I've done yesterday.

Comment: @Toto Do you have a link to meta or a guideline that shows consensus that an answer like "it is impossible" should always be a comment, not an answer?

Comment: No, I haven't .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129434/discussion-between-gantendo-and-toto).

Comment: Yeah, well. I clearly am aware of the settings option and I clearly said that I'm after an alternative. Thanks for putting in your time.

Comment: In newer versions of Notepad++ (eg.: 8.4.8), the checkbox is in Settings>Preferences > Cloud & Link > Clickable Link Settings

Answer (score -3):

You have to use regular expressions or regex for short when using the find and replace feature in whatever code editor you’re using.

Notepad++, Notepad 2 mod, Sublime Nova, Text, Atom, Jetbrains, Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio, Coda, Expresso, Textmate - they all support regular expressions.

Here are 2 good websites for testing out regular expressions.

https://rubular.com/

https://regex101.com/

Here’s some good tutorial websites.

https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/php-regular-expressions

https://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Comment: Sorry, but what is the purpose of find and replace in this scenario?? I don't see how your answer relates to my question. Are you sure you wanted to post it here?

Comment: My answer does successfully answer your question. When using find and replace in Notepad++, in the text box for find you have to type in the regular expression and in the replace text box you have to leave it blank. I’m on my phone and I’m waiting for my laptop charger to come in the post so I can’t post a screenshot or video yet. You’ll have to wait.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Well, no. My question is not answered by your answer, because I still don't know what to do to remove the link from the text. Posting links about generic regex usage does not help with my question at all.

Comment: My laptop charger came in the post today. I'll post a sufficient answer later today with the relevant step by step instructions and screenshots.